# Advantages of Canon-style lens contact pins

Tags: canon, nikon, lens-mount

I've wondered about this for some time. There are essentially two way the electric pins frm the camera body to the lens can be configured: either pointing forward like in the Canon bodies, or pointing towards the center like the Nikon bodies.

I have noticed in the recent teasers from Nikon that they are adopting the Canon style pins. Are there any obvious advantages to this configuration?

PS. I am not sure if this question fits better here in Photography or Electronics.

Comment: The Pentax KA mount, from 1983 (and on) uses yet a different arrangement: outward-facing but _on the bayonet mount itself_ rather than recessed. (I believe this predates both Canon EF and Nikon AF by several years.) The Minolta A mount is from 1985 and has internal, forward-facing pins. I'm not sure "Canon style" is a great descriptor.

Answer (score 3):

*This is a guess:* Nikon has likely had to make design decisions as a result of choosing to maintain mount compatibility. Since they now appear to be changing the mount, they are free to account for different factors, such as cost and ease of manufacturing.